# React Select custom IndicatorContainer

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to target the indicator container to customise the css, I'm importing customstyles and managed to manipulate the rest of the component. Just not the indicator container...

Tried targeting it by using the custom style "indicatorContainer"
`const customStyles = () => { return { indicatorContainer: (provided) => ({ ...provided, padding: 0, height: "24px", }) }; };`

The react-select library says IndicatorsContainer. Tried that also but no prevail...

Also tried "0px" instead of 0 too...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, as there are several things to style around the indicator. You can style the `indicatorContainer`, the `clearIndicator`, the `indicatorSeparator`, the `dropdownIndicator`... You just have to target your styling to the correct element.